# INSPIRE XSD schema definitions

Tags: c#, metadata, geonetwork, inspire

I was looking for `INSPIRE` metadata `XSD` schema definitions on the Web, but nothing found. Only something like [THIS](http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/). But that resource is "a little" messy... I wanted to use `xsd.exe` to autogenerate `C#` classes that could be easily serialized into `XML` that is `INSPIRE` compliant. The problem is in finding that schema file. Could you point me where to download it?

Comment: The schema you found are for INSPIRE   data sets. metadata is a profile of ISO 19139

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood this right, you are looking for something like this:

https://github.com/geonetwork/schema-plugins

Or http://metadata101.org

Answer (score 1):

Working from a WMS/Inspire getcapabilities doc I get:

```
<WMS_Capabilities xmlns:srv="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/srv/srv.xsd" xmlns:gmd="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gmd/gmd.xsd" xmlns:gco="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd" xmlns:inspire_vs="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0" xmlns:gml="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:inspire_common="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.3.0" updateSequence="724" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://ags103a26:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0 http://ags103a26:8080/geoserver/www/inspire/inspire_vs.xsd">
```

So I would say you need - http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0 & http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0.

But I haven't walked the schemas to see what they pull in (but I guess your tool should handle that).

Comment: I tried to convert `common.xsd` and I get something that is not INSPIRE metadata compliant class... :(